# Comparing two sets of XML data without loading all the comparison data into memory

Tags: java, xml, algorithm, comparison, sax

So I have two XML files that are being parsed for information. I'm trying to think of a way to determine what elements from one XML file are missing from the other XML file. Now currently the results for both XML files are loaded into two different arrays but this is not good because its a lot of data to hold on to.

I need to somehow figure out what is missing from one file without loading all the data permanently into memory since the XML files in question can be very very large.

Here is an example of the xml. Just imagine the other file is missing one of the weakness.I'm already using the SAX parser to get the actual data.

```
 <weaknesses>
   <wakness status="new" severity="low" id="14876">
     <cwe id="133" href="http://cwevis.org">Title1</cwe>
       <tool code="STRING" category="PERFORMANCE" name="aaa"/>
        <rule name="Method invokes inefficient new String(String) constructor"/>
         <locations>
         <location path="Catcher.java" type="file">
         <line end="93" start="93"/>
          <description>stuff</description>
         </location>
         </locations>
    </weakness>

   <weakness status="new" severity="low" id="14877">
     <cwe id="138" href="http://cwevis.org">Title2</cwe>
       <tool code="PARAMETER" category="SECURITY" name="bbb"/>
        <rule name="Servlet parameters unsafe"/>
         <locations>
          <location path="Catcher.java" type="file">
         </locations>
   </weakness>

   <weakness status="new" severity="low" id="14878">
     <cwe id="500" href="http://cwevis.org">Title3</cwe>
       <tool code="FINAL" category="asd" name="vvv"/>
         <rule name="Field isn't final and can't be protected from malicious code"/>
          <locations>
           <location path="Course.java" type="file">
           <line end="56" start="56"/>
           <description>stuff </description>
           </location>
          </locations>
   </weakness>
 </weaknesses>
```

Note: I'm programming this in Java and Assume that the elements are not sorted. the two ideas that come to mind are the easy way of loading both sets and comparing one against the other which dosent solve the memory problem. The other one would be to keep parsing the xml over and over without storing things but then its very process inefficient.

Comment: Do you need to deep-check the `weekness` elements to determine they are equal, or just compare the id's?

Comment: After thinking about it, I think Id's would work, then I would search for that id and pull its respective data.

Comment: Make a class containing the elements you need to check, implement equals; parse the first file populating a set of that class; close and parse the second file removing from that set; time complexity is n+m (worst case), space is n (times the bytes of the comaraison class instance)

Comment: Thanks! Thats a good idea, If you make a formal answer I will accept it.

Comment: Honestly, I am not very in the mood of writing the code for you, you will find many bits and pieces searching in this site. Just take care in choosing the best-fitting data structure among the available java collections. If you are in trouble, come back and ask a more specific question

Comment: But what if the first file doesn't contain weaknesses that the second file have? Then in this case they would be ignored.

Comment: java `Set.remove()` will return a boolean telling you if the object was actually deleted. If you get false, save it somewhere else, that's exactly what you asking for.

Comment: why would set.remove(item) ever return false? The act of me calling remove should remove it....right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you compare xmlfile A against B. You first fill a set X with all A elements while parsing file A; while you parse file B, you try to remove from the stack X whatever elements you find. If you get `true` (it is removed from the set), you go ahead. If you get `false` (it was not in the set X), you save it in set Y). At the end of parsing file B, stack X will contain all elements in A and not in B; stack Y will contain all elements in B which are not in A.

This requires you to implement an entity class realizing the weakness object, which implements `equals` (for the remove call to work), and eventually the `Comparable` interface (a sorted collection may be a better fit for some dimensions of this problem).